# Gem version conflict is not resolved by uninstalling

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I want to try this gem called `everton` (https://github.com/rubiojr/everton), but when I try to install it, it complains that I need `thrift_client`. I install that with no problem, and go to install everton again. No! It wants `thrift_client 0.6.0` specifically. I install that one. Now, everton installs okay.

However, when I go to run my program, I get this unsurprising error:

```
/home/thomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1625:
in `raise_if_conflicts': 
Unable to activate evernote-1.2.0, because thrift_client-0.6.0 
conflicts with thrift_client (>= 0.8.1) (Gem::LoadError)
```

However! I went ahead and removed the 0.8.1 verson, and checked that `gem list` has only the versions I want, and the error remains the same. Does `gem uninstall` leave something behind I need to dig out? What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using rvm, be sure to make sure you're using the proper ruby version

```
rvm 1.9.1
```

and use rvmsudo to install the gems

```
rvmsudo gem install everton
```

Comment: what do i do if i'm not using rvm

Comment: what are you using? there are other options such as rbenv.